# Permission Denied error while building Azure web app in node JS

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I am trying to do a manual build of an Azure web app that is running on a Windows instance using Node JS and Express. I am getting this error message when I run npm run start;

```
node:events:505
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied :::4000
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1372:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1508:7)
at Function.listen (C:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\home\site\wwwroot\index.js:39:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1399:8)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
errno: -4092,syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 4000
```

I have tried changing the port number, carefully checked the index.js, carefully  checked the package.json, rerun npm install, and am still getting the same error. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This does work perfectly in localhost.

Answer (score 0):

- Most probably this issue is because of lack of a `web.config`  file in the folder.
- Now instead of creating `web.config` on our own If we deploy the code using git it will create the file for us.
- In azure there are multiple option such as azure GitHub action, azure repo and bitbucket etc.

Here I have deployed using local git and I am deploying an express app.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the slow response! We do already have a web.config. This is such an odd issue, as we don't have any issues with the other 50 web apps we are hosting on Azure.